# Unsorting a sorted TreeView list in win32/winapi

Tags: c++, sorting, winapi, treeview

this is the sorting code. When the user toggles the sort button this runs and sorts the TreeView

```
void TreeView::sort(HTREEITEM hTreeItem, bool isRecusive)
{
    ::SendMessage(_hSelf, TVM_SORTCHILDREN, TRUE, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(hTreeItem));
    if (!isRecusive)
        return;

    for (HTREEITEM hItem = getChildFrom(hTreeItem); hItem != NULL; hItem = getNextSibling(hItem))
        sort(hItem, isRecusive);
}
```

win32 already provides a TVM_SORTCHILDREN message to sort a TreeView. I want to unsort the treeview list to the previous state, when the user toggles the sort button from an on state to an off state.

One way to solve this; is to store the treestate before sorting the treeview. Can someone guide me on how to implement this?

Comment: Somewhat related, note that your function sorts recursively regardless of the value of `isRecusive` parameter. You are passing `wParam == TRUE` to `TVM_SORTCHILDREN`, thus instructing it to sort recursively. The loop afterwards is a no-op.

Comment: The sort operation loses the original order. If you didn't preserve it somewhere (e.g. in user data associated with each item), then there's no way to recover it. If you did preserve it, you can use `TVM_SORTCHILDRENCB` ; you'd have to provide the callback that compares two items so as to put them in their original order.

Comment: Good spot @IgorTandetnik, ill fix the recursive variable. 
regarding the actual problem, i'll try to preserve the TreeView List and use TVM_SORTCHILDRENCB.